# How to access a volatile object from a view script?

Tags: php, zend-framework, software-design, zend-view

I'm using `Zend_View`, I wrote a view helper, this view helper sets some variables.

One of my object uses `Zend_View` to render some text, and, I want to set an option to my Object but inside the view using the view helper.

Let's say I've the following view script:

```
<?php
$this->setRenderedDateTime(new Zend_Date());
<p>Foo bar</p>
```

My 'Object' do something like:

```
$object->getView()->render();
```

What I want is, before to `render()`, I want to `getRenderedDateTime();`

Any ideas?

I've some ideas, but I'm wondering what the best way to implement such things.

Comment: Your question is REALLY HARD to understand. Try to use **actual** code, instead of some generic `$object`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I think you might need:

Make use of fluent interface. Make your view helper return itself for the main call. Look how view helper HeadScript is made :)

```
//in view
/** @return My_View_Helper_UberCool */
$helperInstance = $this->uberCool();
$helperInstance->setVariable($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what it is you are asking, but have you looked into using Zend_Session for handling storing the RenderedDateTime?

If this is something that needs to be saved on a per-object basis, then I'm not sure why you need to be using Zend_View to store that objects state.